# How to load models in django app

Tags: python, django, models

So, I'm trying to upgrade my django project from 1.7 to 1.9. And I'm getting the terrible "RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and either isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS or else was imported before its application was loaded. ". All my models have the app_label defined. However, I think I'm having a really hard time loading libraries that load other models.
What should I do? How to I load these libraries after my app (inside the project) get started?

Comment: show your project settings.py. Also, have you imported ContentType model anywhere in your code?

Comment: Is `'django.contrib.contenttypes',` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Yes, the contrib was on INSTALLED_APPS. I discovered my problem. One of the libs that I imported, from a third party, wasn't Django1.9 compatible (they're the ones responsible for the AUTH part). Thanks for all the help!